# Is it possible to detect HOSTS file resolution vs DNS resolution

Tags: dns, hosts

For diagnostic purposes I would like to be able to find out if a customer has a hostname failure because of a HOSTS file entry. Is it possible to detect that a DNS query was resolved by HOSTS or DNS?

(Of course I'm curious about multiple OSes: Windows, HPUX, AIX, Linux, Mac)

I suspect it may be possible if I could bypass the hostname resolution sequencing configuration of the machine. Of course reading the HOSTS file directly is an option but if there's an in memory problem (i.e. virus, or just changed to remove the misconfiguration but not taken effect yet) then it wouldn't be helpful.

Comment: If you don't tell us what API you are calling to map from name to number, we can't tell you if there's an answer to your question.

Comment: DOH! The API doesn't matter. I'm curious about calling via C, Java, Python, C#, Ruby, etc... I have discovered already that doing a direct DNS query for something setup only in the HOSTS file will fail (of course).

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, if you are looking up `server1` you can compare the IP address printed in the output of `ping server1` with the output of the `nslookup server1` command.

This URL states that on Windows, `nslookup` does not use the `hosts` file:

https://serverfault.com/questions/95036/what-can-cause-a-dns-lookup-to-ignore-a-hosts-file-entry

Both `ping server1` and `nslookup server1` print the IP address they associate with `server1`, but `ping` will use the `hosts` file (on my system) and `nslookup` does not.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to add this information to a diagnostics box so that a call to tech support would be able to easily discover that someone's mucking with their hosts file and that's why the app doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, you could use `getent` to filter the "database" used by the "hosts resolving" service:

```
# Request that looks only in file (/etc/hosts)
getent -s hosts:files ahosts mydomain.tld

# Request that looks only in dns (as defined in /etc/resolv.conf)
getent -s hosts:dns ahosts mydomain.tld
```

The `database:service` could be found in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`